# Output content file to specific folder while building project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, build-process

I have VS 2012 project with structure like this:

```
Project
   Folder1
      file.xml
      schema.xsd
      code.cs
   Folder2
      code1.cs
      code2.cs
```

I set `Copy to output directory` property of `file.xml` and `schema.xsd` to `Copy always` and want to output them to the same folder where assemblies outputed (`bin\Debug`) but they always copied to folder `bin\Debug\Folder1`. Is there a way to achieve my goal without moving files to the root of the project?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I do have the same question for VS 2010.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I recommend you do this with a Post-built event script. It's not as hectic as it sounds, and gives you loads of flexibility.

- Right-click on your project and select **Properties**.
- Go to the **Build Events** tab and click **Edit Post-build...**

(See screenshots below)

You can now specify shell commands to be executed after each successful build of your project. The following achieves the example in your question:

```
copy "$(ProjectDir)Folder1\file.xml" "$(TargetDir)"
copy "$(ProjectDir)Folder1\schema.xsd" "$(TargetDir)"
```

`$(ProjectDir)` and `$(TargetDir)` are *macros* which insert the respective values relevant to your project. You can select and insert macros from the macro menu in the edit window.

The quotes are included above, because your `ProjectDir` and `TargetDir` might resolve to full paths that include spaces, and that will break the `copy` command if the spaces aren't there.

[image: Opening Porject Properties]

[image: Editing Post Build]